# bow’r, affin’d and pow’r

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

**What usage is the following abbreviations?**

> ```
>   ‘Not boskiest bow’r,
>   When hearts are ill affin’d,
>     Hath tree of pow’r
>   To shelter from the wind!’
>                    from The Woodlanders by Thomas Hardy
> ```

Comment: I'm closing this as GR because a dictionary search for [bow'r](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/all/?q=bow%27r) [pow'r](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/all/?q=pow%27r) [affin'd](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/all/?q=affin%27d) yields candidate words as the opening result, all similarly formed.

Comment: Poetic license:license or liberty taken by a poet, prose writer, or other artist in deviating from rule, conventional form, logic, or fact, in order to produce a desired effect.

Comment: The abbreviations like that, apostrophes are used to show that what might have been two syllables has been reduced to one (helping show how the poetic meter is supposed to be).

Answer (score 3):

In poetry, it's not un common to contract suffixes like these, to allow the words to fit the meter and/or make a rhyme. This poem has examples of both.

- *bow'r* and *pow'r* de-emphasize the *-er* suffix, so that the lines end on an accented syllable.
- *affin'd* changed the pronunciation of the *i* to match that in *wind*, so the two words rhyme.

Comment: You are right in that *bow'r* and *pow'r* are spellings used in poetry to indicate that this is a one-syllable pronunciation rather than a two-syllable one. For *affin'd*, I have no idea why Hardy would spell it like that. If Shakespeare had done this, he would be indicating a two-syllable pronunciation rather than a three-syllable one. However, I am pretty sure that by Hardy's time, nobody used the three-syllable pronunciation. I am very dubious of your assertion that this means it's pronounced to rhyme with *wind*, though.